# confusion in left shift operator in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I am trying to use left shift operator on the 16 bit binary representation of a integer

Code written is below:

```
def showbits(x):
    return bin(x)[2:].zfill(16)
i=5225
print "Decimal %d is same as binary" % (i)
print showbits(i)
for j in range(0,5,1):
    k=i<<j
    print "%d right shift % gives" % (i,j)
    print showbits(k)
```

Output:

```
Decimal 5225 is same as binary
0001010001101001
5225 right shift  0ives
0001010001101001
5225 right shift  1ives
0010100011010010
5225 right shift  2ives
0101000110100100
5225 right shift  3ives
1010001101001000
5225 right shift  4ives
10100011010010000
```

The main problem is that when it is shifting the leading '1', it is not vanishing but it is increasing one more bit...

Any solution for that?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to do weird bit shift stuff in such a high level language like python?

Comment: @wim: Because sometimes you need to bitshift values. When interoperating with other systems that send you bytes containing flags, for example. Every tried to parse a binary format? Another use is to multiply a value in exponents of 2.

Comment: @wim for example i'm implementing dns packet parser and guess, i need to manipulate with bits. For me is so weird to hear, that in language X you shouldn't do the stuff Y coz it is language X ! just stupid...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd *mask* the resulting value, with `&` bitwise AND:

```
mask = 2 ** 16 - 1
k = (i << j) & mask
```

Here `16` is your desired bit width; you could use `i.bit_length()` to limit it to the minimum required size of `i`, but that'd mean that *any* left shift would drop bits.

The mask forms a series of `1` bits the same width as the original value; the `&` operation sets any bits to 0 *outside* of these:

```
>>> 0b1010 & 0b111
2
>>> format(0b1010 & 0b111, '04b')
'0010'
```

Some side notes:

- You are *left* shifting, not right shifting.
- You appear to have forgotten to a `d` in your debug print:

  ```
  print "%d left shift %d gives" % (i,j)
  ```

  There was a lone `%` there that combined with the `g` for `gives` to make `%g` (floating point formatting).
- You can use:

  ```
  def showbits(x):
      return format(x, '016b')
  ```

  to format an integer to a 0-padded 16-character wide binary representation *without* the `0b` prefix.

Comment: @Kroltan: Because that's the standard bitwise operation to limit a value to a certain bit-width.

Comment: it's giving error: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Comment: @user3223301: sorry, that was an error that the outage of SO just now prevented me from fixing for you.

Comment: Oh, so Python will automatically expand the bit-width of a number to fit all the information? Interesting.

Comment: yes, python is a bad guy with non fixed int type and coz of this i need to write 14 bit mask to cut 2 hi bits =(

Answer (score 0):

Because Python does some magic to prevent this condition, known as an overflow, from happening. It does this by adjusting the type:

```
>>> i = 5225
>>> type(i)
<type 'int'>
>>> j = i << 16; type(j); bin(j)
<type 'int'>
'0b10100011010010000000000000000'
>>> j = i << 32; type(j); bin(j)
<type 'int'>
'0b101000110100100000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> j = i << 64; type(j); bin(j)
<type 'long'>
'0b10100011010010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> j = i << 128; type(j); bin(j)
<type 'long'>
'0b101000110100100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

If you want to limit the bits you want to work with, do as Martijn suggests and use a 16-bit mask.

```
>>> j = 0xffff & (i << 12); type(j); bin(j)[2:].zfill(16)
<type 'int'>
'1001000000000000'
>>> j = 0xffff & (i << 13); type(j); bin(j)[2:].zfill(16)
<type 'int'>
'0010000000000000'
>>> j = 0xffff & (i << 14); type(j); bin(j)[2:].zfill(16)
<type 'int'>
'0100000000000000'
>>> j = 0xffff & (i << 15); type(j); bin(j)[2:].zfill(16)
<type 'int'>
'1000000000000000'
>>> j = 0xffff & (i << 16); type(j); bin(j)[2:].zfill(16)
<type 'int'>
'0000000000000000'
```